# Why might my Inno Setup project not be executing these lines as expected?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I want to nuke these keys. When I do so manually, it disappears from the Add/Remove Programs dialog.  But running the installer with this doesn't remove them.

Code:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM32; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{F0908904-B8CF-46E2-8AA1-2DC981ABDEEE}}"; Permissions: users-full; ValueType: none; Flags: deletekey;
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{{F0908904-B8CF-46E2-8AA1-2DC981ABDEEE}}"; Permissions: users-full; ValueType: none; Flags: deletekey;
```

Comment: That doubled closing `}` brace looks suspicious. Note that you must escape only opening `{` braces, not the closing ones. Then we could guess that those keys are under the user's root (not `HKLM`), but that's where we end up. These lines should do what you expect, just remove that `Permissions` parameter. It's pointless here.

Answer (score 1):

@TLama, the double closing brace was more than suspicious, it was the cause of the lines not performing as expected.  Removing the extra `}` did the trick - thank you!